# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException

Tags: java, velocity

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

I am trying to make a connection with `amazonMechanicalTurk` using Java API.

```
Exception in thread "main"
 org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Error initializing
 log: org.apache.log4j.Logger object set as runtime.log.logsystem is
 not a valid log implementation.
    Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException:
    org.apache.log4j.Logger object set as runtime.log.logsystem is not a
    valid log implementation.
```

Comment: Please post the complete and formatted stacktrace (use code formatting i.e. every line should be preceeded by 4 additional spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to add some other Velocity libraries to my project.
My project only had the **Apache Velocity** jar file, then from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=velocity), I also added **Velocity-Dep** to my Maven project and Yesssssssssss! VICTORY!
Still asking why?!! because my project was working well until I decided to update java-aws-mturk library to version 1.7.0; then after I got that error!

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor, working with Velocity I've learned that is better to shut down his damn log:

```
//disabling Velocity log
Velocity.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am quite new in java. I can find the code related to velocity in my program but it is ".class" and in fact I cannot make any changes into that. Would you please help me, where should I write a line of code that you mentioned previously?

Comment: First you have to find your Velocity context configuration (if it's done via xml or .properties file I can help you, if it's done on class side unluckily if you can't change the code you cannot change the property).